# In LLVM IR, store an integer into the second element of a vector

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want to store an integer into the second element of a vector now. The vector is `<2 x i64>`, now I only have its pointer `<2 x i64>*`. 
I have tried several methods to get the pointer to its second element but they are all failed. 
I tried to use getelementptr but I can't set the *Ty* parameter  as `i64` or `i64*` or it will report an error which says "`assert (PointeeType == cast<PointerType>(Ptr->getType()->getScalarType())->getElementType());` failed". If I set it to NULL, I can just get a `<2 x i64>*`. 
Then I tried to use `IRBuilder.CreateExtractElement` to extract the second element of the vector first. But after I get the `i64`, I don't know how to get its pointer, since I have to set the store's second parameter as `i64`.

Comment: https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#insertelement-instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you cannot "store" to second element of the vector in general (what if it's in register – what will be the address?).

Use insertelement instruction (https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#insertelement-instruction) to put scalar element into a vector.

Comment: hi, can I ask a small favor of you, could you take a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50308253/creating-local-variable-in-function-llvm ?